# Why does PHP emit compatibility error when inherited interfaces are used for type hinting?

Tags: php, interface, compatibility, type-hinting

Please take a closer look at the following two code blocks. **Error** and **Warning** produced are placed underneath the respective code block.

It seems very **interesting** to me! I think both should act in the same way, and those should not emit any error or warning as they seems logically valid to me.

Is this a **PHP bug**, or I'm missing something?

*By the way, I believe the question and the code is very simple and self-explanatory, so I'm not going for further explanation. :-)*

```php
interface A {}

interface B extends A {}

class X implements A {
    public function test() : A {}
}

class Y extends X implements B {
    public function test() : B {}
}
```

**Fatal error:  Declaration of Y::test(): B must be compatible with X::test(): A**

```php
interface A {}

interface B extends A {}

class X implements A {
    public function test( A $a ) {}
}

class Y extends X implements B {
    public function test( B $b ) {}
}
```

**Warning:  Declaration of Y::test(B $b) should be compatible with X::test(A $a**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I think I found the answer myself.**

As an inherited interface can have additional declarations (an inherited type can have additional attributes), those are logically completely different, and hereby the Error / Warning emitted by PHP are absolutely correct.

Thank you for reading the question and the answer. Hopefully this will help others understand the use of interfaces as type in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Good news! The first part will work as of PHP 7.4. :-)